# Samsung Galaxy S plus is becoming unresponsive when locked

Tags: lock-screens, system-freeze, samsung-galaxy-s-plus

My samsung was working away perfectly yesterday and then was on my bedside locker when I tried to check the time the lock screen came up very faded almost its hard to describe but it was unresponsive otherwise e.g would not open would not turn off etc. so I pulled the battery (this may be bad for it I'm not sure) so I turned it on and it was working away fine but then I locked it and it became completely unresponsive, no lights nothing so I pulled the battery again and the same thing is happening.

Does anyone know whats causing this or a way to fix it. I'm hoping it's not serious as I just bought this 2 weeks ago!

Comment: can you please give more specific data, like OS using? Rooted or non-rooted? Custom lock app?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a custom lock app, it may be to blame.  Try reverting to the stock lockscreen.

Answer (score -1):

Is it running a custom ROM?  If so, install another one.

If not, take it back/exchange it.

Comment: I would not think it's a custom rom as by the way he posted and described it, the OP would not know the first thing about custom roms, and also, it was bought two weeks ago...

Comment: @t0mm13b, hence the second sentence.  From what would I infer the person hasn't installed a custom ROM?  Is this something I should just ask in the comments?  I still think the answer could potentially be helpful to future visitors even if the asker hasn't installed a custom ROM.